# How to solve the following differential equation. y is a function of x.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve the following diff equation
$$2xyy'=y^2-x^2$$

Comment: Make a substitution $y(x)=z(x)x$

Comment: Alternatively, note that $2yy' = (y^2)'$ so you can recast your equation as $x(y^2)' = y^2 - x^2$. Setting $y^2 = z$ we have $xz' = z - x^2$. This is a very solvable ODE.

Answer (score 0):

Scaling: $x \to \alpha x\,,\quad y \to \beta y.\quad$ The new equation is given by
$2xyy'= y^{2} - \left(\alpha/\beta\right)^{2}x$. It doesn't change its form whenever $\alpha/\beta = \pm 1$. Also, it means that $\pm y/x$ enjoys this symmettry. Then, use $y\left(x\right)/x = {\rm z}\left(x\right)$ as @Artem already suggested. There is a nice book ( Lie Algebras, etc… ) about these techniques ---> [http://www.amazon.com/Applications-Difference-Equations-Differential-Integral/dp/1420083090/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1379815990&sr=8-1&keywords=Dorodnitsyn](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1420083090)

Answer (score 0):

In this problem divide $2xy$ through out the equation resulting in $y'= \frac{1}{2}[\frac{y}{x}-\frac{x}{y}]$. In here substitute $y=vx$ or $x=vy$ depending on your choice. I like $y=vx$ a lot. So I will proceed with it. For $y=vx,y'=v+xv'$. Finally the substitution will yield $v+xv'=\frac{1}{2}[v-\frac{1}{v}]$ which gives $xv'= \frac{-1}{2}[\frac{v^2+1}{v}]$. this is in variable separable form. Separate the variables and integrate to obtain a solution.

Remember to substitute back $v=\frac{y}{x}$ in the solution to obtain the final result.